# Keep all individual raster pixel after applying the Raster to Polygon tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, raster-conversion, singlepart

I have a **raster** with a *float* data type, which I want to **convert to polygon** *maintaining each pixel*. I mean ***that each pixel will be a single part polygon on the output polygon layer***.

However, when I obtain the polygon layer, ***some pixels are aggregated*** by the "Value" field. (See the image below, with these aggregate areas highlighted). Just what I do not want.
[image]

Before converting the float raster to polygon, I **have to pass the float raster to an integer** raster, and I reckon that this is the issue. Because when I apply the "Int" conversion, *the raster obtained is aggregated by the pixel value*. (See the image of the int raster attribute table).

Is it ***a process or tool to get each pixel on the final polygon?***

[image]

Comment: I don't see an option in the tool, but as a workaround you might multiply your floating point raster by 100 or 1000, then run the Int tool, and then convert that to polygons.  This reduces truncation and is much less likely (but still possible) neighboring cells get the same value.  You can then divide the gridcode by your multiplier in the polygon layer to get your original raster values.  Alternately  you could create a grid to match the raster cells and intersect it with your polygonized layer.

Comment: Try https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012696. Or install QGIS and use "Raster pixels to polygons" tool. Or install OpenJUMP and use "Create polygon grid from raster" tool.

Comment: Raster to point, pointid  to raster, raster to polygon.

Answer (score 1):

1. First convert Raster to point
2. Graphic Buffer for points (linear unit has to be half of the resolution of the raster).